# Mongo Query with conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

my documents structure is like this:

```
{ 
    'name': 'name1', 
    'sources': [
       {
          'site': 'www.example1.com', 
          'first_seen_date': ISODate("2018-04-09T15:43:49.941Z"), 
          'last_seen_date': ISODate("2018-04-09T15:43:49.941Z")
       },
       {
          'site': 'www.example2.com', 
          'first_seen_date': ISODate("2018-02-09T15:43:49.941Z"), 
          'last_seen_date': ISODate("2018-04-10T15:43:49.941Z")
       }
    ] 
}
```

I want to find documents with a specific 'name' and 'site' - if exist to update the last_seen_date. if only the name exist and the site doesn't exist - add the site to the array with site, first_seen_date, last_seen_date . can I do it in one query? The only solution I can think of contains two different queries.

Comment: Different queries or use language of your choice to execute everything in single flow using logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 `updateOne` queries, one with `$ne` & `$set` and one with `$push` **one after the other**. This will still make it "atomic" operation even if you use more than 1 application node:

```
db.test.updateOne(
    {
        name: 'name1',
        'sources.site': 'www.example3.com'
    },
    {
        $set: {
            'sources.$.last_seen_date': new Date()
        }
    }
)


db.test.updateOne(
    {
        name: 'name1',
        'sources.site': {$ne: 'www.example3.com'}
    },
    {
        $push: {
            sources: {
                site: 'www.example3.com',
                first_seen_date: new Date(),
                last_seen_date: new Date(),
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Unfortunately, `$addToSet` by an object key is not available. This would have make this problem much easier. It seems that this feature request is long time opened:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13841